# Why is this usage of concatentation in StringBuilder's constructor 100X faster than calling append()?

Tags: java, performance, stringbuilder

I stumbled upon a bizarre performance issue related to the `StringBuilder`'s `append` method.  I noticed what appeared to be a foolish mistake - string concatenation during the use of the `StringBuilder` constructor (this even shows up as a warning in the NetBeans IDE).

**Version 1**

```
int hash = -1;     //lazily computed, also present in Version 2
int blockID = ...  //0 to 1000, also present in Version 2
int threadID = ... //0 to 1000, also present in Version 2
boolean hashed = false;       //also present in Version 2

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    if(!hashed){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(blockID+":"+threadID);
        hash = s.toString().hashCode();
        hashed= true;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

Millions of these objects are created during runtime, so I thought by making the following change, it would provide some speedup:

**Version 2**

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
    if(!hashed){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(blockID);
        s.append(":");
        s.append(threadID);
        hash = s.toString().hashCode();
        hashed = true;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

WRONG! Turns out, Version 2 is literally 100X slower than Version 1. Why???

**Additional Info**

I am compiling against Java 6 (customer requirement), and I am using Oracle's JVM.

My performance test involves creating a million of these objects and throwing them into a HashMap. It takes half a second to do it using Version 1, but almost 50 seconds to do it using Version 2.

Comment: By creating a million of these objects and throwing them into a HashSet and timing it. It takes half a second to do in Version 1, but almost 50 seconds to do it in Version 2.

Comment: would be interesting to see the generated bytecode difference for those.  if the perf thing were true (dubious until I see how you profiled this), it would imply this entire block would make more sense as just `hash = (blockID+":"+threadID).hashCode();`

Comment: Why use a StringBuilder in the first place? What's wrong with `blockID + ":" + threadID`? And why building a String to compute the hashCode of 2 integers? Let the IDE generate the code for you: it will be much more efficient.

Comment: I must admit that I'm a little surprised by the factor 100 but why should we assume that the JVM itself handles string concatenation in a less efficient manner than provided by a class from the standard library?

Comment: I too have seen `+` to be faster than using `StringBuilder` - even in a loop where using a `StringBuilder` is supposed to be faster.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Have you checked the byte code to see if the `+` was still there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your test as your first case is actually doing.

```
public int hashCode(){
    if(!hashed){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(
                  new StringBuilder(blockID).append(":").append(threadID).toString());
        hash = s.toString().hashCode();
        hashed= true;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

In other words it is doing everything in the second case and more so it will be slower.

In short, I suspect your test is wrong, not that you are getting better performance.

Comment: I suspect you're right about there being something wrong with the test itself. I was using JUnit to run this test. When I duplicated the test code and ran it apart from JUnit, the performance differences disappeared. There must be something asymptotically slower in some of the assert calls I was making when compared to the simple `if` statements I used to replace them in the non-JUnit version of the test. Very odd ... good catch!

Answer (score 14):

Because you're inadvertently setting the initial capacity of the `StringBuilder` instead of appending `blockID` to it. See [constructor documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder-int-).

> public StringBuilder(int capacity)
>
> Constructs a string builder with no
>   characters in it and an initial capacity specified by the capacity
>   argument.

Try this instead:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(9);
s.append(blockID).append(':').append(threadID);
```

Comment: Upvoted, because this definitely makes sense, but it turned out not to be `StringBuilder` at all - JUnit was introducing some REALLY strange performance behavior for reasons I still can't figure out. Isolating my test from JUnit fixed the perceived issue in performance.

Comment: I believe my blockID stays small enough in the test that the overhead of allocating too much or too little `StringBuilder` initial capacity doesn't overcome the bigger issues present when using JUnit to run the test. Even so ... my usage of the constructor was erroneous, so I appreciate the help!